# Generating n random variables, and multiplying them together c++

Tags: c++, random, vector

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the user enters n = 2, what I want to happen is for two (or n) random numbers to be multiplied together. It should work for any n, and where the random numbers are between 0 and 1.

```
I have been using this for random numbers between 0 and 1
(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX for this.

So to break it down further
n= 1
random_number = random_number 
n = 2
random_number = random_number * random_number
n = 3
random_number = random_number * random_number * random_number 
n = ...
random_number = random_number * random_number * ...
```

The problem is the random numbers have to be unique as well. For example, for the case of n = 2, it should be ...

```
 random_number = (unique)random_number * (unique)random_number
```

To complicate the matter further, let's also say I have m (not static) divisions, and I create a vector of size m^n. I also need to create this vector of size m^n to be...

```
 vector = [rand*rand, rand*rand, rand*rand, rand*rand]
 for the case when n = 2 m = 2
```

How would I go about doing this in c++?

Comment: I strongly suggest you consider boost::random, if you are using C++03; or std::random, if you are using C++11. The reason is the standard rand() is much biased. This is observed when I was doing random walk simulation several years ago. I am unsure if these days rand() has improved, but using boost::random::mt19937 is much safer.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix a maximum limit, say `N = 1000` such that `N >= m`.

1. Populate a vector from `0` to `1000`, say `I`
2. Shuffle `I` using `std::random_shuffle()`

Pick the first `m` numbers, and divide each by `N`.

This should be it.

The larger the value of `N`, the larger is the space from which you will be serving numbers.

Alternatively, you can just set `N` to 1000, and shuffle `I` as I mentioned, and then for each number in `I`, generate a final random divisor picked from an array that may look like  `[10, 100, 1000, 10000,...]`

Comment: The numbers produced this way will all be multiples of (1/N)... that doesn't seem very random, at least not in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the division is happening because of the maximum limit we used. The numbers thus picked will be random numbers from 0 to 1.

Comment: There are millions of possible values between 0.0 and 1.0 that are expressible with an IEEE float, but this algorithm only ever returns a very small subset of those -- there are just N (i.e. 1000) possible values it can generate, spaced evenly between 0.0 and 1.0.  Whether or not that is 'good enough' depends on what the random values are going to be used for, but e.g. for cryptography it wouldn't be considered usably random.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The value of `N` can be made arbitrarily large thereby increasing the possible values that will be returned.

Comment: Heh, that's true.  Set it to (2^32-1) to get the full resolution?  :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Well, you could :), I have added an update that can lead to a higher resolution without this much memory, with some tradeoff on randomness.

Answer (score 2):

To get `n` random numbers just repeatedly use `rand()` to generate them.  If you want them to be unique, put them in a `std::set<int>`.  This way, you can check if it was generated already.  Once you have the unique set, do whatever processing you need to do on them - i.e. make them fall between 0 and 1 and them multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

For U(0,1) random number mean value is 1/2. Therefore, multiplying `N` uniform random number will produce result on average equal to 1/2<sup>N</sup>. Which means even for few tens of generated numbers product on average would be very small